# Cannot connect to internet with Wifi to my home network

Tags: wi-fi

I've a Moto E which won't connect to the internet on my home Wifi. It shows "Connected" but I cannot browse etc.

I've other devices successfully connected to this router. Also this Android phone successfully browses via the 3G internet as well as other Wifi routers.

What could be the next step to debug this problem? The Router is configured to use WPA2-AES. There is no MAC whitelist / blacklist or any such access control.

I installed the Wifi Analyzer app on this phone and it successfully sees the access point. It is listed as using Channel 6.

Any ideas?

Comment: While I never searched for the reason, for some folks, changing the DNS to a public DNS (like Google's 8.8.8.8) works.